# While trying to run gpt-engineer, I tried this command 'python main.py example', but recieved 'No such file or directory'

Tags: ubuntu, openai-api, chatgpt-api

error I got

[image]

I used this tutorial to follow along. [https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ceMuK0xUtSY&t=6s]
Got stuck at time 4:21 of the video. I dont know how to fix the issue with the command. I expected the command to run and use the prompt file from the projects/example. I dont think there is any issue with the code. what can I do?